# Why video tag has multiple source tags inside it?

Tags: html, video, mp4

I have never worked with video tag before. Recently in one of my project I wanted to add video tag. As I was going through stackoverflow examples, I found many have suggested using multiple source tags containing webm, mp4 and ogg formats. Any reason why we do this? Is it compatibility issue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it compatibility issue?

Yes. Here's [a list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats) of formats and respective browsers that support them.